# Improve horrible, multiple-sub-query SQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, subquery

How would you improve the following product i18n retrieval SQL to NOT use sub-queries?

```
SELECT
 l.code,
 l.rtl,
 l.name,
 (SELECT title FROM product_i18n WHERE product_id = :product_id AND culture = l.code) AS title,
 (SELECT description FROM product_i18n WHERE product_id = :product_id AND culture = l.code) AS description,
 (SELECT keywords FROM product_i18n WHERE product_id = :product_id AND culture = l.code) AS keywords
FROM
 language AS l
WHERE
 l.status = 1
ORDER BY
 IFNULL(l.sort, l.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT
 l.code,
 l.rtl,
 l.name,
 p.title,
 p.description,
 p.keywords
FROM
 language AS l
INNER JOIN product_i18n p ON (p.product_id = :product_id AND p.culture = l.code)
WHERE
 l.status = 1
ORDER BY
 IFNULL(l.sort, l.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
SELECT
 l.code,
 l.rtl,
 l.name,
 p.title,
 p.description,
 p.keywords
From
 language AS l
inner join product_il8n p on p.culture = l.code and p.product_id = :product_id
WHERE
 l.status = 1
ORDER BY
 IFNULL(l.sort, l.id)
```

Comment: It was the unnecessary parentheses in the on clause that did you in. :D

Comment: Hah!  Yea sometimes I get kinda parentheses happy.  Upvote from me none the less.